# Is this the correct way to perform CRUD with stored procedures?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a task archive some database tables. To simplify everything, I basically have to do the following:

1. Retrieve some rows from table 1 based on some condition
2. Insert these rows into a table in the backup database
3. Delete those rows from table 1

and I have to perform these operations on several tables.

This [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3082201_2/Implementing-CRUD-Operations-Using-Stored-Procedures-Part-1.htm) is telling me to create separate SP based on the different CRUD operations (one for each of CRUD). As one can see, the steps I need to perform are `READ`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`. Then based on the article, I will need 3 SP for each of my tables. So if I have 10 tables I need to back up, then I need to write 30 SPs?

Could someone please tell me if this is the right practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning on running this task one a regular basis? If not and also if the tables required won't change often, then you could do it in one stored proc. If the tables will change a fair amount you could make a stored proc per table. I had a similar issue in which I just create an 'archive' stored proc for each object/table.

Comment: @AlexTyman, Yes, the tasks will run as Cron jobs on a regular basis and the tables will change very often. So you are suggesting me to create separate stored procs for each CRUD operation for each table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking on behalf of my learning curve: When I started with databases, I didn't care that much about things I do now. The easiest and more "logical" way is to do the CRUD in one SP, since according to your scenario things are small.
But when it comes to scalability you really need them to be separated. It's a good habit to start building on your programming.
Another thing to point out is the more order you can apply to your DB, the better.

About having to CRUD 10 tables. No, you don't need 30 SPs (maybe you will do, but that would be a very unlikely scenario). You can use variables, parameters and stuff so you perform READ to several tables using parameters (for table names, etc). Same with other CRUD's operations.

So, in short: Maybe you end up having a big and complex SP for just READing tables. But that's how it is, you work hard one time, then you re-use time and time again. (this is a good thing to do; it will definetely help/save you in the future if you don't know OOP)

Comment: I see what you are saying, thanks. I have also thought of this idea, but the columns differ quite a bit between the tables. Though I can parameterize the table names, how can I parameterize the table columns? As you can see in the article I linked, the author explicitly states all column names.

Comment: select column_name,* from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'YourTableName' is the way to go for that, you get them list them, store them, and move on on whatever you have to accomplish.

Comment: in your `select column_name,*` did you mean `select column_name.*`? Also, I forgot to mention that I am using Sybase.

Comment: No, it was just column_name, and then * in case you wanted to check all the info contained in information_schema.columns. But column_name will do the job.

Comment: Daniel, I am having trouble with getting a list of the column names from a table on my Sybase database. I've searched online and I have tried using `syscolumn` and `sysobjects` and none seem to work. Would you know how I could get a list of the column names once I know the table name?

Comment: sysobjects is for older versions of SQL, you're probably running things on a SQL Server 2008 or so. In that case, you have to use SYS.OBJECTS. As far as column names go, you need to select * from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable' (again, I've used * but you can strecht your SELECT the way you want)

Comment: My Sybase server is returning me the error `information_schema.columns` not found. It just won't recognize anything I try. Could it be my permissions are insufficient to select these system tables?

Comment: Not having permission for SYS.Objects is very common, but still your error is not the no-permission-error. Check the server version you're working into, it's like those objects are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a stored procedure to outline some sort of function that you want to perform.  You are trying to archive data in a table, so I would call the stored proc dbo.Archive_Table1.  The "Archive_" is a prefix denoting the operation of the procedure, and the suffix is the object (or objects) that you want to act on.

For a quick example, let's say you want to archive data in several tables that are all related to data about cars.  dbo.Make, dbo.Model, dbo.Sales, etc.  You could create a single stored proc called dbo.Archive_Cars, which acts on all of these tables.  It's verbose enough to tell anyone looking at it what you are trying to do.

In your new stored proc, feel free to do anything you want.  Do inserts and deletes together!  It'll make your life a thousand times easier not to have to deal with 30 SPs.  Sure, you might end up creating some of the other CRUD SPs later, but do it on an as-needed basis.

Your outline in the question is perfect; just convert it to code and you're set.